# Can the CSS for sidebar link colors be changed?

Tags: feature-request, design, related-questions

When searching for whether my question has already been asked, I get lost in all the similar questions.

I would like to see a modification of the CSS for the links. The `:visited` color is already different from the `:link` color, but it is so similar that I can't tell which questions I've already read. I would suggest that the `:visited` color is a shade of purple instead of blue (following the old standard), giving a visual clue for which questions I have seen.

This is my first time at Meta, but I see that there are quite a few similar questions to mine. It seems obvious to me that indicates it needs attention.

The first image below is what I see on Meta. Can you tell that I visited the 2nd link? Not only is the difference very small, but they are both blue. Since all sites are different, there is nothing obvious to tell me that slightly darker blue is visited. The second image below is from StackOverflow. When presented with a list of very similar question titles, half visited and half not, I can only guess which ones are which, but mostly I can't tell any difference.

It's such an easy fix to improve the usability tremendously.

[image: related list on Meta]
[image: related list on StackOverflow]

Comment: Just as a note, you can set (most) browsers to not allow sites to override your browser link colour settings. And setup the colours you prefer for links visited etc. I know this would effect other sites, hence just a comment

Comment: That type of setting would not work well for people like me, since I design sites and need my browser to render it as coded.
Besides, why not make this site the most useful possible without the user having to set an option they might not have? 
I do have a browser extension to load different CSS depending on domain, but again, why not fix it for everyone?

Comment: I'm not against your idea, as I said, it was just "a note" :)